# Streaming Netflix through Wifi kills all other devices

Tags: wireless-router, netflix, wii

I have a "Belkin N150" Router. My current setup is wired connection to my personal tv and xbox with wireless going to the Wii and Bedroom laptop.

Anytime I try streaming Netflix Instant Queue on the Wii, every other device has problems. The Wii works fine but everything else's connection is destroyed. Streaming through the Xbox doesn't create any issues for other devices.

What kind of issue is occurring and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3):

This could be related to a problem people experienced with their Apple devices (iPad, iPhones, etc) in conjunction with OpenWRT/DD-WRT based routers. In that instance, the [Netflix app was setting off DNSmasq](https://dev.openwrt.org/ticket/8134), a service designed to stop DNS rebinding attacks. If you happen to have a router running custom firmware, updating to the latest version might solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue an Internet radio station, not *Netflix.* I found I could not connect, or even `ping` the station's stream URLs.

I verified that this issue is indeed due to the `Prevent DNS-rebind attacks` feature of some router firmware (*Tomato, DD-WRT, OpenWRT,* etc.).

Disabling the feature in the router's configuration solved the problem and allowed streaming from these sites.

After this I could also `ping` the URL and discovered why it was triggering the DNS-rebind protection: The site's URL resolves to a private IP address in the range `10.0.0.0 - 10.255.255.255!`

Not sure why *Netflix* or any streaming service would use URLs that resolve to private addresses. Does anyone else know?